# How to output the first digit of a number even if it's negative?

Tags: haskell, recursion, math, negative-number

In haskell, I used the following to get the first digit of postive numbers:

```
firstDigit :: Int -> Int
firstDigit n
    | n < 10    = n
    | otherwise = firstDigit (div n 10)
```

How could I solve the case for negative numbers? Would I just have to check for them before running the rest of the program or is there something more intuitive?

Answer (score 5):

You can first make a call with `abs` and then use a recursive function, so:

```
firstDigit :: Int -> Int
firstDigit = go . abs
    where go n | n < 10 = n
               | otherwise = go (div n 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with the "first digit" of a negative number being itself negative, then one way would be to keep dividing all the way to 0 and then back up one step.

```
firstDigit :: Int -> Int
firstDigit n = case n `quot` 10 of
    0 -> n
    n' -> firstDigit n'
```

This keeps the same code shape as your original, and doesn't require an extra check for negativity as the first step (not even hidden behind a call to `abs`). You do need to switch from `div` (which rounds down) to `quot` (which rounds towards zero) -- though you probably want to do that anyway if you don't take this approach, as it's marginally faster on most computers.

Comment: This relies on details of the behaviour of `quot` in a pretty obscure way. Getting an approach like this wrong can easily lead to infinite recursion, I wouldn't recommend it (unless the performance benefit is measurable and deemed worthwhile).